# Is this slicing behavior defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I am dealing with Python's slicing and I encountered unexpected results.

**Example:**

```
print([1, 2, 3][0:-4:-1])
```

Returns `[1]`

```
print([1, 2, 3][0:-3:-1])
print([1, 2, 3][0:-2:-1])
print([1, 2, 3][0:-1:-1])
```

Each of these returns `[]`(as expected).

How does this happen?

Thanks, Reyha24.

Comment: Are you asking only about the first example?

Comment: @zondo: Yes. The other ones are clear to me.

Comment: This is defined behavior. It's similar to `[1, 2, 3][2:3]`, just going backward instead of forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices), the first item (start) is inclusive.  The second argument (stop) is *ex*clusive.  When a stop of -3 is given, that means to go from `1`, to `1`.  Since the stop is exclusive, that excludes the only item, and the result is empty. When -2 is given, it translates to index 1.  As soon as index 0 is given, you have already passed index 1 because the step is negative.  Therefore, the result is empty.  You get something similar with -1. Taking -4 from the end, however, becomes -1 because there are only three items in the list.  Going from 0 to -1 with a negative step is possible: index 0 is included, index -1 is not because it shows up later in the list.

Comment: Thanks, zondo. Your answer ist great! I think I mixed up something. Can you tell me how the other three examples get to their results? Because if I follow that rule, the element at index 0 should be included, right?

Comment: @Reyha24: Very good point.  I think I misunderstood, too.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is clearer if you reverse the slice and convert to regular indexing.  Since python uses half-open intervals, `[0:-4:-1]` converts to `[1, 2, 3][-3:1]`.  `-3` in this case corresponds to index `0`, so this converts to `[1, 2, 3][0:1]`, which is just the first element.  The second case, `[0:-3:-1]`, converts to `[-2:1]`, which is `[1:1]`, which is empty.  The third case converts to `[2:1]`, and so on.